# Add rows to worksheet depending on a cell value

Tags: vba, excel

I have googled and tried various different things to get this to work but still can't find a solution.

I am still trying to learn about macros and VB so any help would be appreciated.

Basically, what I am after is a cell value on one worksheet to be the amount of rows on a second worksheet.

[Picture showing what I am after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5jGK.png)

[image]

As described in the picture, the value of the source cell (number of payments) varies depending on the term/frequency/value of agreement.
I would then like that number of rows be allocated in the next worksheet, with sequential numbering.

This is what I have managed to fumble about with so far....

```
    Sub ExtendByValue()  
'
' ExtendByValue Macro  
' Extends the rows by the number of repayments  
'

'
    Sheets("Agreement Tems").Select  
    Range("C8").Select  
    Selection.Copy  
    Sheets("Payments").Select  
    Range("M1").Select  
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _  
        :=False, Transpose:=False  
    Rows("8:8").Select  
    Application.CutCopyMode = False  
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove  
End Sub
```

Any help with this is appreciated.

Comment: You want to insert 156 rows before 8th row in payments?

Comment: Read this site about not using Select in your code. Then build a loop around the last line (the one with `.Insert`) to get the number of rows you need.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Rows("8:" & (sheets("agreementterms").range("c8").Value + 8)).select
 Selection.insert shift:=xldown
```

incase you have value issues as specified in comments use the below.

```
 Rows("8:" & (sheets("agreementterms").range("c8").text + 8)).select
 Selection.insert shift:=xldown
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked, but I did have a few issues with mismatch errors. The result in C8 is rounded up from converting years, months and weeks into the payment frequency - so even though the displayed result is in a whole number, the true value of the cell has decimal places and therefore Excel can't fathom how to put .7 of a row in.  I have gotten around that by just having to physically type the result into a separate cell and use that as the reference.

Comment: Use .text instead of .value.  If u show only round number this should work

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub ExtendByValue()
'
' ExtendByValue Macro
' Extends the rows by the number of repayments
'
    Dim nRows As Long

    nRows = CLng(Sheets("Agreement Tems").Range("C8")) 'get the integer part of cell "C8" value in "Agreement Tems" sheet
    With Sheets("Payments")
        .Range("B8").Resize(nRows - 1).EntireRow.Insert 'insert nRows-1 below cell "B8" of "Payments" sheet, so as to have nRows with this latter included
        With .Range("B8").Resize(nRows) 'of these nRows ...
            .FormulaR1C1 = "=row()- row(R7)" ' ... fill column "B" with a formula returning integer form 1 to nRows ...
            .Value = .Value ' ... and finally get rid of formulas and leave only values
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```